# вывод сообщения об ошибке на экран HttpClient

Tags: javascript, angular

Работаю с api openweathermap.
Как вывести сообщение об ошибке на экран и в консоль если неверно указан город?
Заранее благодарю за ответ

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {
  url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
  apiKey = 'cd568793ed4c1a5791ef68c832393f50';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getWeatherDataByCityName(city: string){
    let params = new HttpParams()
      .set('q', city)
      .set('units', 'imperial')
      .set('appid', this.apiKey)
    return this.http.get(this.url, {params});

  }

}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherService} from '../weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forecast',
  templateUrl: './forecast.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forecast.component.css']
})
export class ForecastComponent implements OnInit {
  weather;
  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
 getCity(city){
    this.weatherService.getWeatherDataByCityName(city).subscribe(data =>{
      this.weather = data;

    })
 }

}
```

Comment: ну а дате что приходит ? на this.weather = data; не вариант повесить условие ?)

Comment: @АлексДанилин я только учусь, вы не могли бы показать как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: да я сам ток учусь...тож ангуляр зацепил) но мне так не подсказать... закинь дату в консоль - покажи, что там приходит

Comment: вторым параметром в subscribe передается функция, которая вызывается в случае ошибки в observable